# Derivatives of operations on eigenvectors with repsect to matrix

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

My question is: Given a matrix $A$ and its eigenvector $v$ which corresponds to $A$'s maximum eigenvalue, is there a closed form formula to calculate the derivative

$$\frac{\partial(u^Tv)}{\partial A}$$

where $u$ is an unrelated vector?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I check matrix cookbook which shows

$$\partial v = (\lambda I-A)^\dagger\partial(A) v$$

where $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue, $\dagger$ is the symbol 
of pseudo-inverse. But I still don't know how to calculate the desired derivative.

Comment: What is the "pseudo-inverse"?

Comment: @AlexM. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the eigenvalue equation, and take differentials
$$ \eqalign {
 0 &= (A-\lambda I)v \cr
   &= dA\,v + (A-\lambda I)dv \cr
 dA\,v &= (\lambda I-A)dv
} $$
For notational convenience, let $M=(\lambda I-A)^{\dagger}$.

Then proceeding to the least squares solution, we obtain the cookbook result
$$ \eqalign {
 dv &= M\,dA\,v \cr
} $$
From there, we can pre-multiply by $u^T$ to obtain
$$ \eqalign {
 u^Tdv &= u^TM\,dA\,v \cr
 d(u^Tv) &= p^TdA\,v \cr
   &= pv^T:dA \cr
} $$
where $p=M^Tu\,\,$ and the colon represents the [Frobenius product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product), $\,X\!:\!Y=tr(X^TY)$.

Since $df = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}):dA$, the derivative must be
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac{\partial\,(u^Tv)}{\partial A} &= pv^T \cr
   &= M^{T}uv^T \cr
  &= (\lambda I-A^T)^{\dagger} \, uv^T
} $$

Comment: Thanks, @greg ! That's what I want. I forget to use the definition of differential.

Comment: Please be aware that the cookbook result comes with all sorts of restrictions on $A$, i.e. it must be real, symmetric, with distinct eigenvalues. Also the eigenvector must be normalized, $\|v\|=1$.